# Angular Universal setting X-XSRF-TOKEN header in request

Tags: angular, typescript, csrf, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm trying to set up Angular Universal SSR correctly to work with an XSRF token.

Current situation: I'm on the /profile route, and the page is rendered on the server. In the console, I see an error:

```js
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    lazyInit: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  status: 401,
  statusText: 'Unauthorized',
  url: 'http://localhost/api/public/user',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for http://localhost/api/public/user: 401 Unauthorized',
  error: { message: 'Unauthenticated.' }
}
```

And the browser briefly displays the login screen (due to the authentication guard) before hydrating and showing the profile page.

I would like to make the profile page display immediately without the brief flicker of the login screen. To do this, I attempted to extend the server request with an XSRF token so that the request to the backend is made with the proper token during rendering, and the user's profile is returned.

Here's the relevant code:

server.ts:

```js
server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    // @ts-ignore
    req.myCustomData = {
        xsrfToken: getXsrfToken(req.headers.cookie)
    };
    // @ts-ignore
    console.log('token on server', req.myCustomData);

    commonEngine
        .render({
            bootstrap: AppServerModule,
            documentFilePath: indexHtml,
            url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
            publicPath: distFolder,
            providers: [
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
                { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res },
                { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req }
            ],
        })
        .then((html) => res.send(html))
        .catch((err) => next(err));
});
```

xsrf-token.interceptor.ts:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        console.log(this.request.myCustomData);
        const serverReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.request.myCustomData.xsrfToken),
            withCredentials: true
        });
        return next.handle(serverReq);
    }
}
```

In the server console, I see the console log containing the token.

To receive an HTTP 200 OK response from the backend, the Cookie must contain the XSRF-TOKEN, and the header must include X-Xsrf-Token. Authentication on the backend is performed using Laravel Sanctum.

Can someone please advise me on where I might be making a mistake and if I'm on the right track? There is very little information about Angular SSR in the official documentation. I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: HttpClientXsrfModule will do the work for you: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule  (Just be aware that it excludes absolute URLs... so baseURLs should be relative or just ".")  The token won't be added (or checked on the backend) when using GET, though.  It's not clear what the initial request is here...?

Comment: I have also tried that. In the app.module, I have it configured like this:

importProvidersFrom(
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
        cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    })
),
But I still get a 401 Unauthorized error. I have set up an APP_INITIALIZER, so the first request goes to /user to verify whether the user is logged in.

Comment: if that's a GET you won't need anti-csrf.  A session probably hasn't begun yet... that would start after authorizing the user in most circumstances, though sometimes they'll start a temporary session before login and then start another afterwards.  Even if there's an initial session begun the anti-csrf token will only be needed when posting credentials.  The server (not from any .ts file...) will set the cookie that your client-side code would read so be sure that part is happening.